# NSGregorianCalendar to NSCalendar

Tags: iphone, xcode, date, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I'm searching for a technique/method that can transform NSGregorianCalendar into a timestamp. I can make a double timestamp but not a integer timestamp

Here's my code:

```
//Create the timestamp of the date
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
// NSTimeInterval is defined as double
NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];
NSLog(@"%@", timeStampObj);
```

But it gives me a timestamp of the type 1311780128.540395 And I want just 1311780128

Thanks to help me

Comment: `transform NSGregorianCalendar into a timestamp` ??? `export the date as US (DDMMYYYY) but it isn't the aim!` ??? Could explain more? Are you saying you want the date returned by your calendar to be a timestamp and what do you mean it isnt the aim.

Comment: @Joe : I've modified my initial post ;-) sorry for my language(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the integer portion, cast the double to an int:

```
NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt: (int)timeStamp];
```